# Python cross-compiling for Mac on Linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, macos

I have Python scripts on Linux machine, and I want to make executable file from them. But, I need that executable for Mac. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked into [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)?

Comment: Yes, but I want on Linux machine to make file for Mac OS X.